# sessions versus cookies

Tags: session, cookies

Which is the difference between sessions and cookies. I know that sessions are server side, and managed by the server, and the cookies are client side and managed by the browser.

I don't know why, but I see those things as rendundant. Which data have to be keept in a session variable and which on cookies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Session is implemented with cookies. You would normally save in a cookie things like the user id, or some identifier that will allow you to know who the user is, and use that information as a key for your session variable on the server side.

Most importantly, you wouldn't want any secret information being stored on the client side, since cookies can easily be stolen (from a security point of view).

Don't forget that HTTP is stateless, so cookies are just a way to bypass this.

Answer (score 1):

In short, cookies are more persistent than sessions. As soon as you close your browser, the session information is gone. Therefore a session has no way to store information about a website/user pair. Cookies do, and are used for things like allowing you to stay logged in to a website, or storing preferences for that website (e.g. language).

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between cookies and sessions is that cookies are stored in the user's browser, and sessions are not. This difference determines what each is best used for.
see
 http://php.about.com/od/learnphp/qt/session_cookie.htm

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are for small data. They can only hold strings. 
In session variables you're able to store objects in the server memory.